# custom field in opportunity which gives number or count of closed won opportunity associated with the account of that opportunity?

Tags: custom-field

Thank you in advance.
My requirement is I need to create a field in opportunity object which gives count of all closed won opportunity for the account of that opportunity.

Let suppose Account A has two closed won opportunity B and C, so that on B or C opportunity page we need to create a number field which gives the same count for Account A which is 2. I suppose roll up summary field will not work here because it creates aggregate (sum, count, Max and Min) of child record and gives an output in Parent record.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a roll-up summary on Account object, they support record filtering. Then you would need to add a formula field on opportunity which is reading this roll-up field.

If you don't want the value to update throughout time, you could copy the value on creation instead of using a formula. This depends on what you want to achieve.